# Send inquiry on specific price list

Tags: jquery, html, css, contacts

I'm building website which will include table with price lists. Now i want to create a code, which will open a new pop up window so that user can send inquiry about specific prices.

I have created a dropdown list with plans, and a popup button. When user selects specific plan and clicks popup, a new popup form should open.

The code doesn't seem to be working and the popup doesnt appear.

Any clue why?

**Thanks**

**HTML**

## Select your Domain name

```
<select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Domain name --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">domain1</option>
    <option value="february">domain1</option>
    <option value="march">domain1</option>
    <option value="april">domain1</option>
    <option value="may">domain1</option>
    <option value="june">domain1</option>
</select>
<!--END DOMAIN NAME-->
```

**HTML POPUP FORM**

```
<!--POPUP FORM-->
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<div id="abc">
    <!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
    <div id="popupContact">
        <!-- Contact Us Form -->
        <form action="#" id="form" method="post" name="form">
            <img id="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <hr>
            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
            <textarea id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <a href="javascript:%20check_empty()" id="submit">Send</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<!-- Display Popup Button -->
<h1>Click Button To Popup Form Using Javascript</h1>
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
<!--END POPUP FORM-->
```

**CSS**

```
#abc {
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:.95;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
position:fixed;
background-color:#313131;
overflow:auto
}
img#close {
position:absolute;
right:-14px;
top:-14px;
cursor:pointer
}
div#popupContact {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:17%;
margin-left:-202px;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif
}
form {
max-width:300px;
min-width:250px;
padding:10px 50px;
border:2px solid gray;
border-radius:10px;
font-family:raleway;
background-color:#fff
}
p {
margin-top:30px
}
h2 {
background-color:#FEFFED;
padding:20px 35px;
margin:-10px -50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0
}
hr {
margin:10px -50px;
border:0;
border-top:1px solid #ccc
}
input[type=text] {
width:82%;
padding:10px;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway
}
#name {
background-image:url(../images/name.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
#email {
background-image:url(../images/email.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
textarea {
background-image:url(../images/msg.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px;
width:82%;
height:95px;
padding:10px;
resize:none;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway;
margin-bottom:30px
}
#submit {
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-color:#FFBC00;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #FFCB00;
padding:10px 0;
font-size:20px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:5px
}
span {
color:red;
font-weight:700
}
button {
width:10%;
height:45px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color:#cd853f;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
cursor:pointer
}
```

**JS**

```
function check_empty() {

if (document.getElementById('name').value == "" ||             

document.getElementById('email').value == "" ||       

document.getElementById('msg').value == "") {
    alert("Fill All Fields !");
} else {
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
    alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
}
}
//Function To Display Popup
function div_show() {
document.getElementById('#abc').style.display = "block";
}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
document.getElementById('#abc').style.display = "none";
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/3ndew7oh/

Comment: create a form with a dropdown which has all plans. On click just pop open the form and select the clicked plan as default in dropdown

Comment: Unfortunately, we're unable to help without any research into the topic or readily available code. Please expand your question with any code you've attempted to use to make it easier for SO users helping you find a solution.

Comment: @CerlinBoss so i have created a drop down and a popup. i have edited the post. when i click "popup" nothing happens. any clue why?

Comment: @fox can you create a fiddle and share with us?

Comment: @CerlinBoss please see updatet post. When user chooses one of 6 domains from dropdown list and clicks send inquiry, the pop up window should appear and send inquiry for CHOSEN domain name. How do i do that? How do i send inquiry for specific chosen domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
#abc {
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:.95;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
position:fixed;
background-color:#313131;
overflow:auto
}
img#close {
position:absolute;
right:-14px;
top:-14px;
cursor:pointer
}
div#popupContact {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:17%;
margin-left:-202px;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif
}

p {
margin-top:30px
}
h2 {
background-color:#FEFFED;
padding:20px 35px;
margin:-10px -50px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0
}
hr {
margin:10px -50px;
border:0;
border-top:1px solid #ccc
}
input[type=text] {
width:82%;
padding:10px;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway
}
#name {
background-image:url(../images/name.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
#email {
background-image:url(../images/email.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px
}
textarea {
background-image:url(../images/msg.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:5px 7px;
width:82%;
height:95px;
padding:10px;
resize:none;
margin-top:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:40px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway;
margin-bottom:30px
}
#submit {
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-color:#FFBC00;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #FFCB00;
padding:10px 0;
font-size:20px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:5px
}
span {
color:red;
font-weight:700
}
button {
width:10%;
height:45px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color:#cd853f;
color:#fff;
font-family:'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
cursor:pointer
}
</style>

<select id="mounth">
    <option value="hide">-- Domain name --</option>
    <option value="january" rel="icon-temperature">domain1</option>
    <option value="february">domain1</option>
    <option value="march">domain1</option>
    <option value="april">domain1</option>
    <option value="may">domain1</option>
    <option value="june">domain1</option>
</select>

<h1>Click Button To Popup Form Using Javascript</h1>
<button id="popup" class="popup">Popup</button>

 
<!--START POPUP FORM--> 
<div class="modal fade" id="popup-moda">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
      </div>
   <form action="#" method="post" name="form">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="domain"></div>
    <input required id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    <input required id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
    <textarea id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </div>
   </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<!--END POPUP FORM-->


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.popup').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#domain').html('<b>' + $('#mounth').val() + '</b>');
  $('#popup-moda').modal('show');
  return false;
 });
});

</script>
```